# Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired) exception with Rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

I have problem with delivering emails on production server.
When mailer processed new message, calls exception `Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired)`

My smtp settings:

```
#settings.yml
production:
  smtp:
    address:        smtp.gmail.com
    port:           587
    domain:         mydomain.net
    user_name:      username@gmail.com
    password:       password
    authentication: plain
    enable_starttls_auto: true
```

My environment settings:

```
  #production.rb
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = Settings.smtp.symbolize_keys
```

From logs:

```
Sent mail to username@gmail.com (30010.1ms)
I, [2014-10-15T12:59:22.371563 #19779]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30051ms
F, [2014-10-15T12:59:22.373984 #19779] FATAL -- :.
Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):
app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Comment: I think, problem in ipv6 configuration on my VPS. 
When I try call from terminal command `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` connect takes about a 1 minute

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My VPS provider (DigitalOcean) blocked SMTP on IPv6 by default :(

I had to disable IPv6 on server with next config:

```
# /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Apply settings:

```
$ sysctl -p
```

Uncomment the next line in `/etc/gai.conf` to prefer IPv4:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
```

And remove IPv6 DNS from `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844 # remove lines like this 
nameserver 8.8.8.8 #don't remove
```

Then restart application and Nginx (optional)

Comment: I did it bu `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` and `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` still doesnt work..

Comment: After doing this I am unable to deploy on server getting error #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as root@******: exit>

Comment: Port 25 worked for me. I tried a ton of ports, and it may depend on your ISP or something...Not an expert in this.

Comment: It helped me to solve problem with email sending from Rails App after migration.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, in my case it was because Google Cloud Compute platform blocks outgoing connections to SMTP servers outside of Google's domain on ports 25, 465, and 587.

To fix this problem we had to connect to a non-standard SMTP port (most API-based mailer platforms support 2525 as well for this reason).

Comment: Port 25 worked for me. I tried a ton of ports, and it may depend on your ISP or something...Not an expert in this.