# How to setup Action Mailer using SendGrid to send emails to Devise users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi I'm trying to create simple app. After devise user is logged in can create event as soon as create this email will be send to him.

```
    def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.user = current_user
    @event.save
    @user= current_user
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    respond_with(@event)
  end
```

I've change on production and development files

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'https://mydomiantest.io' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'username',
  :password => 'mypassword',
  :domain => 'mydomiantest.io',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I've also created user_mailer.rb in mailers

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'no-replay@mytestsite.io'
    def welcome_email(user)
        @user = user
        @url  = 'mytestsite.io'
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
      end
    end
```

It is takes some time after creating event and then I don't have any email, I have created account on site grid what else do I need to do?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.1.6 and ruby ruby 2.1.5p273

Comment: Check the log file to see what is happening.

Comment: right you must check the log file then figure out the error

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30359ms

Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):

Comment: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` and check log

Comment: you can refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388090/netopentimeout-execution-expired-exception-with-rails-mailer

Comment: There is time out error, funny thing is when I use gmail to send this email is working fine so should'n be anything wrong but for some reason not working...

Comment: Are you sure you have "confirmable" enabled for devise? What actions are you expecting to trigger emails?

Comment: After registration I've setup regards email, something is blocking me but don't know what I've missed.