# Not being able to send email from spree 3, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm having hard time configuring smtp with a rails app. I have done it many times in the past without spree which worked fine. But for some reason, Im not able to get my smtp settings work with spree to send emails.

Here is my configuration:

```
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 465, # Doesn't work with 587 either 
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'email@gmail.com',
    password:             'emailPassword', 
    authentication:       :plain, # Tried :login too
    enable_starttls_auto: true
   }
```

I get a couple of errors listed below `Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout` and `Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired`

Below is the stack trace

```
Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `initialize'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `open'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `tcp_socket'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in `block in do_start'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `do_start'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:2141:in `do_delivery'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `block in deliver'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionmailer-4.2.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:543:in `block in deliver_mail'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
... 6 levels...
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/pamio/dev/rails_apps/local/store/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/pamio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'2.1.1 :004 > reload!
```

I've tried setting up mandrill thinking that gmail might have been blocking my emails but that didnt work either.

Note: I want to be able to configure SMTP with spree3 and I'm not using `spree_mail_settings` gem. For some reasons `spree_mail_settings` didnt work for me.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Edit 1: I know my smtp config is fine but may be I must set some `spree` related config vars that would let spree use the new config just like in previous versions of spree. I have explored the docs and did not find any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`?

Comment: Google might be blocking access from an unknown place.

Comment: I think `domain` should be set to your domain or can be left out entirely.  I use port 587 and :login.

Comment: @RAJ the out for that is `0`

Comment: @Coderhs I tried turning on lesssecureapp but no luck, i dont think google is blocking that or I would be notified.  Steve Klein, I tried them both but no luck.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388090/netopentimeout-execution-expired-exception-with-rails-mailer)?  If you are running on a Google server, it might be the port you are using.  Otherwise, I would check carefully to ensure you are not using IPV6.

Comment: @steveklein, yes I have seen that already but no luck. I have disabled ipv6 but no luck. The important think here is that I'm not even able to get my mandrill account working. I think it's got to do something with spree. I'm not sure though

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix can be disabling IPv6. Add following lines to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
#disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then from terminal, you can confirm IPv6 (0 means enabled & 1 means disabled):

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

Comment: I did disable that and yet the I get `Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired`

Comment: Care to explain why disabling may solve the issue ? although, it didn't :)