# execution expired exception when using actionmailer rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, actionmailer

I used actionmailer in two ways. First one with gmail smtp with configuration:-

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp # be sure to choose SMTP delivery
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => "587",
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => "some-username@gmail.com",
    :password             => "some-password",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

That works very fine. The mail was sent.

The issue is when I decide to use my mail server in my server with configuration:-

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp # be sure to choose SMTP delivery
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "mail.xgram.xyz",
    :port                 => "25",
    :domain               => "xgram.xyz",
    :user_name            => "some-username@xgram.xyz",
    :password             => "some-password",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

With this configuration, I got this error in terminal

> Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):

and this error in the browser

> execution expired

In addition, `mail.xgram.xyz` as server name is valid, because when I change it to any arbitrary name, The error will be

> getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Can any one help me ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable ipv6 in your server configuration. Once it's done you will not see the error.

Comment: Did you mean system configuration which is related to the Operating System, web server configuration which is Apache, or rails configuration?

Comment: Config related to OS. Please refer this 'http://stackoverflow.com/a/26518579/2657566'

Comment: I think this is not IPv6 issue. While in the question in the comment, the guy used gmail configuration which is already works fine with me. My problem is when configuring my own SMTP.

Comment: Port 25 worked for me. I tried a ton of ports, and it may depend on your ISP or something...Not an expert in this.