# getting Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired only sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

My rails application sends emails through a gmail account using mailer. Till recently everything was working fine. But now sometimes I get the error as

```
"Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired"
```

This happens sometimes and sometimes it works. I want to know the reason for this behavior. Is it because of the gmail server having load balancing issues or is it because of some configuration issues in the rails app?

Comment: Have a look at this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388090/netopentimeout-execution-expired-exception-with-rails-mailer

Comment: @Vimsha In the link that you pointed to the mails wouldn't get delivered right. For me the mails get delivered sometimes and only sometimes I get this exception. If it was a problem with ipv6 then I should get that exception everytime right?